# adding facebook like and tweet buttons to an exhisting tumblr theme

Tags: tumblr

I am trying to add facebook 'like' buttons and tweet buttons at the end of each blog post on my tumblr blog. I used the 'minimalist' theme on tumblr. Ive tried just about every method to insert the html properly and nothing has worked. Below it the current full HTML that I am using. If you go to my site right now there is a facebook button and it actually works but there is a ton of blank space underneath that I cant get rid of. Also, it works in Safari but not Firefox which is odd. The fbook code is right before {/block:posts}. I've been able to look at other formats of buttons but they either like my entire page rather than individual posts or I have this same spacing/firefox issue. Can anyone help?

```
    </div>
 </article>
```

Comments

{/block:Posts}

Answer (score 1):

I cant even get that. I've done this task a few times before with other themes and it is no problem at all. It sounds like you didn't uncheck the boxes on Facebook that enable the big black space go back to f.b. and get a new code made from the link page. Do not forget to uncheck the unneeded stuff or that will also be embedded in the code given you.